# Floating DIVs, right-floated div overlaps left divs as window width decreases

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of what I want to do (below).  See the status bar, and notice how the progress bar overlaps the text on the left as the Window size decreases.  I have attempted to do this, but when the Window size is small enough, the right-floated div simply cuts off (on the right).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `absolute` positioning and `z-index`. [See my example.](http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/JFqZs/)

```
<div id="c">
    <div id="l">Some text that would get cut off</div>
    <div id="r">Some text that would cuts off left</div>
</div>

#c
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
#l
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}
#r
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 2;
}
```